# Laravel 5: php artisan migrate:refresh

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am working on a laravel project and each time I change my table (add or remove column) and run `php artisan migrate:refresh`. I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Can't use
>   method return value in write context

Solution tried:

1. run `composer dump-autoload` (Fails)
2. Drop table in database, delete the migration file and restart again (works)

Previous migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

Changed migration file:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

I added the user_id in the change file in the up function

Comment: You seem to have problem in your migration code. Can you post the migration file's content?

Comment: done :) Thank you for helping

Comment: Can you add the Laravel version tag to your question @mushoodbadulla?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this command it works for me

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

However, be careful!  This command will drop all data from your DB:

> Note: The migrate:fresh command will drop all tables from the database and then execute the migrate command.

[as per Laravel docs 9.x](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations).

Answer (score 1):

> try this
>   fire this command

```
php artisan make:migration add_user_id_to_comments_table --table=comments
```

> this will create a new migration file then

```
$table->integer('user_id')->after('id');
```

> then use

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the database and run all database seeds...

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Read [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#drop-all-tables-migrate)